# SQL: How to apply a function (stored procedure) within an UPDATE-clause to change values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-update

the following function deletes all blanks in a text or varchar column and returns the modified text/varchar as an int:

```
 select condense_and_change_to_int(number_as_text_column) from mytable;
```

This exact query does work.

Though my goal is to apply this function to all rows of a column in order to consistently change its values. How would I do this? Is it possible with the UPDATE-clause, or do i need to do this within a function itself? I tried the following:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET column_to_be_modiefied = condense_and_change_to_int(column_to_be_modiefied);
```

Basically i wanted to input the value of the current row, modify it and save it to the column permanantly.

I'd welcome all ideas regarding how to solve scenarios like these. I'm working with postgresql (but welcome also more general solutions).

Comment: What happened when you tried your `update` statement?

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately.  Which database are you using, SQL Server or Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible with an `update`?  Well, yes and sort-of.

From your description, the input to the function is a string of some sort.  The output is a number.  In general, numbers should be assigned to columns with a number type.  The assumption is that the column in question is a number.

However, your update should work.  The result will be a string representation of the number.

After running the update, you can change the column type, with something like:

```
alter table mytable alter column column_to_be_modiefied  int;
```

Comment: " In general, numbers should be assigned to columns with a number type. The assumption is that the column in question is a number."

What do you mean by that? How can I assign a number to a column with a number type? Correct, the input is a text or a varchar column value and the output is an integer. I wrote the function specifically in order to format the text/varchar and then store it as an integer.
Why will the output be a string representation when I return an integer?

Comment: @XmikeX . . . The output is an integer.  It gets assigned to a string column, so it is converted to a string.  After doing the assignment, you can modify the column to a numeric type, as described in the answer.